# Unable to run backend using sls offline --watch

Tags: node.js, serverless

our application  using node js and serverless in backend when iam trying to run the backend locally  using sls offline --watch im getting the error like below
[image]
how can i solve this issue

i have tried using serverless doc to solve and had run the commands from the google, and iam expecting to run the backend with my local api and local db.

the same code is running in another developer laptop with same configuration...

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possible solutions

- Have you checked your package.json file ,scripts.
- Installed cli lib.
  Sorry I wanted to add a comment but my score doesn't allows that

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is to install/reinstall the serverless plugin.

This [Serverless plugin](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#installation)! emulates AWS λ and API Gateway on your local machine to speed up your development cycles. To do so, it starts an HTTP server that handles the request's lifecycle like APIG does and invokes your handlers.

Once you run `sls-offline`. It'll trigger all concurrent events you require. You will have no need to run `watch`.

All CLI options are listed on the [Serverless documentation](https://www.serverless.com/plugins/serverless-offline#installation).

Make sure you have signed in and set up your [AWS config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html) file on your computer